# failed to start LSB :Bring Up down Networking

Tags: centos, centos7

I am new to centos 7 and I am configuring a static IP on centos 7, so I have edited the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scipts/ifcfg-eth0` as following

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
Device=eth0
ONBBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.4.196
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.88.254
DNS1=8.8.8.8
USERCTL=no
```

but when I issue the command

```
systemctl restart network
```

I am getting the error

```
failed to start LSB :/Bring Up down Networking
```

`ip route` show gives me no output

and I have applied the solution that stops networkmanager with the same existing error.

I am able to configure a dynamic dhcp and get a dynamic IP address but not static one what can be possible solutions ?

Comment: Your gateway is not on the same subnet as your local IP.  It should be to work.  But I see that Jenny already explained this in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of IP address, netmask and gateway you have configured do not work together.

The netmask 255.255.255.0 combined with the IP address 192.168.4.196 means that your gateway must be in the span 192.168.4.1-192.168.4.254.

There are three possible solutions:

- Choose a gateway within that span (i.e. one that starts with 192.168.4 instead of 192.168.88).
- Change the IP address to one that starts with 192.168.88 instead of 192.168.4.
- Change the netmask to one that encompasses both 192.168.4.X and 192.168.88.X.

You should talk to your local network administrator to find out which of these solutions is the correct one for your network.

Comment: but i have configured similar centos virtual machines with similar configurations with ip address IPADDR=192.168.4.197 and i have got a static ip

Comment: Were both the netmask and the gateway the same? Because the configuration you have posted is simply wrong.

Comment: no may be we have wrong configuration in our network